# Xcode 6 iOS framework project linker problems

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode6

I've built an iOS framework ("myFramework") using Xcode 6's new framework project type.  I've also written a test app to consume the framework ("myApp").  Both Xcode projects have "Architectures" set to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and both projects have "Build active architecture only" set to "NO".

Unfortunately, "myApp" fails to link because there are "Undefined symbols for architecture Arm7" (or Arm64 depending on whether or not I have a device plugged in).

But how can this be given that both projects build for all architectures?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the simulator and device architecture is different, you need to have separate library built with separate architecture. Solution would be 
1. Build the framework for simulator
2. build the framework for device
3. Use lipo tool to bind the two library and use it in any target simulator or device

You can also automate the process with a post build operation she'll
Script.

When doing step 1. Select Simulator from drop down. (shown Below)
[image]

Comment: Yep, that's a great way to combine those two library.  But my issue is different.  Even if there's not a device plugged in I am building "For IOS Device".  I never build for simulator.  It's under those circumstances that I don't see why one of the architectures doesn't get built.

Comment: Are you selecting simulator? Even if the device is not connected and your target points to `iOS Device` you are building for device.

Comment: Simulator is never selected or built for.

Comment: Attached the picture that shows you are building for simulator

Comment: I understand that.  My targets are build for "target > iOS Device".